# Chrome Developer Console Print New Line Character "\n" in Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

Does anyone know how to toggle chrome devtools to print the newline character "\n" as a new line in the console without using console.log?

It was working fine until the last update but I don't remember how I enabled it before.

[image]

In my example above, when you join the array in the console it is supposed to give me the result like in the console.log but instead prints the newline character. It is super annoying, when these updates mess with settings.

Comment: Curious, what is the use case for this?

Comment: There is no use case for this example but I usually evaluate code in the console when I am debugging an application. It has become super annoying that all the code now needs to be wrapped into console.log for it to actually evaluate correctly.

Comment: There is a huge use case, I copy and paste into Excel all the time

Comment: This is very important for me, maybe would worth opening a ticket

Answer (score 3):

You would have to wrap the object you're trying to output in another `console.log`,
e.g. within the DevTools console use this snippet:

```
const printMeOut = ['Just', 'a', 'list']; // or e.g. Array.from($0.childNodes.values())
console.log(printMeOut.join('\n'))
```

Comment: The question asks for a solution not using `console.log`

Comment: Indeed, must have misread!`Shift+Enter` is the way to go (tested on Chromium/`ungoogled-chromium` `115.0.5790.170`, M1/arm64 MBP). You could then open up DevTools, write e.g. `'abc'` + `Shift+Enter` + `'def'` + `Shift+Enter` + `Enter`=> The output can then be copied and will have the sought after linefeeds. And yes, you have to have at least two lines in your multiline output to have the linefeed show up.

Answer (score -1):

```
+ '\n'
```

rather than join, I think....